# Setting multiple queue name in Laravel5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

This is my first time using Laravel5.1 Queue. I already set it up and it worked fine. But when i tried using [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue) ->onQueue('adding_something'), Below is my code in dispatching the job

```
$command = (new SendInvitation($pricelist_id, $user_id, $cronType, $status, $version, $company_id))->onQueue('add_something')->delay(360);

$this->dispatch($command);
```

after this the jobs stop working. Now they dont get process at all. :(. On my config/queue.php, i tried updating the queue section to

```
'queue' => 'add_something,default'
```

Also tried restarting the php artisan queue:restart but still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the queue listener params. Set the queues in desired priority order like this:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=add_something,default
```

The same goes if you use queue:work instead of queue:listen.

If you left this the way it was your queue listener is probably only listening to default queue.